# KafkaProducer cannot be created due to missing java.security.auth.login.config

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, akka, akka-stream

I am attempting to create a `KafkaProducer` using the `akka-stream-kafka` library.

**INFRASTRUCTURE**

Uses docker-compose, showing the kafka and zookeeper instances only.

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.1.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:5.1.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "29092:29092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:9092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'
```

I can report that I have been able to connect to the cluster using a `kafka-console-consumer`, `kafka-console-producer` on the CLI and the REST API with no issues.

**CONFIG**

This is my typesafe config, I attempt to use a plaintext connection to connect to the client. I am trying to connect to the kafka broker without any authentication.

```
bootstrap.servers="localhost:29092"
acks = "all"
retries = 2
batch.size = 16384
linger.ms = 1
buffer.memory = 33554432
max.block.ms = 5000
```

**CODE**

```
val config = ConfigFactory.load().getConfig("akka.kafka.producer")
val stringSerializer = new StringSerializer()
ProducerSettings[String, String](config, stringSerializer, stringSerializer)
// some code has been omitted here.
Producer.plainSink(producerSettings)
```

**EXCEPTION**

This is the stacktrace that I receive, it tells me that there is no `jaas config`:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:456)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:318)
    at akka.kafka.ProducerSettings.createKafkaProducer(ProducerSettings.scala:226)
    at akka.kafka.scaladsl.Producer$.$anonfun$flexiFlow$1(Producer.scala:155)
    at akka.kafka.internal.ProducerStage$DefaultProducerStage.createLogic(ProducerStage.scala:41)
    at akka.kafka.internal.ProducerStage$DefaultProducerStage.createLogic(ProducerStage.scala:33)
    at akka.stream.stage.GraphStage.createLogicAndMaterializedValue(GraphStage.scala:93)
    at akka.stream.impl.GraphStageIsland.materializeAtomic(PhasedFusingActorMaterializer.scala:630)
    at akka.stream.impl.PhasedFusingActorMaterializer.materialize(PhasedFusingActorMaterializer.scala:450)
    at akka.stream.impl.PhasedFusingActorMaterializer.materialize(PhasedFusingActorMaterializer.scala:415)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a 'KafkaClient' entry in the JAAS configuration. System property 'java.security.auth.login.config' is not set
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasContext.defaultContext(JaasContext.java:133)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasContext.load(JaasContext.java:98)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasContext.loadClientContext(JaasContext.java:84)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:119)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.clientChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:65)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:88)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:413)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:318)
    at akka.kafka.ProducerSettings.createKafkaProducer(ProducerSettings.scala:226)
    at akka.kafka.scaladsl.Producer$.$anonfun$flexiFlow$1(Producer.scala:155)
```

How can I connect to the Kafka Cluster using no auth as required to run locally?

---

I have tried adding `KAFKA_OPTS` as an environment variable to the kafka service in docker-compose as well as adding it to the `application.conf`.

```
sasl.jaas.config="org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='confluent' password='confluent-secret';"
```

In the former case, some associated services such as the  kafka-rest API failed. In the latter case, I get the following exception:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:456)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:318)
    at akka.kafka.ProducerSettings.createKafkaProducer(ProducerSettings.scala:226)
    at akka.kafka.scaladsl.Producer$.$anonfun$flexiFlow$1(Producer.scala:155)
    at akka.kafka.internal.ProducerStage$DefaultProducerStage.createLogic(ProducerStage.scala:41)
    at akka.kafka.internal.ProducerStage$DefaultProducerStage.createLogic(ProducerStage.scala:33)
    at akka.stream.stage.GraphStage.createLogicAndMaterializedValue(GraphStage.scala:93)
    at akka.stream.impl.GraphStageIsland.materializeAtomic(PhasedFusingActorMaterializer.scala:630)
    at akka.stream.impl.PhasedFusingActorMaterializer.materialize(PhasedFusingActorMaterializer.scala:450)
    at akka.stream.impl.PhasedFusingActorMaterializer.materialize(PhasedFusingActorMaterializer.scala:415)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No serviceName defined in either JAAS or Kafka config
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:125)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:140)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.clientChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:65)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:88)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:413)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:318)
    at akka.kafka.ProducerSettings.createKafkaProducer(ProducerSettings.scala:226)
    at akka.kafka.scaladsl.Producer$.$anonfun$flexiFlow$1(Producer.scala:155)
    at akka.kafka.internal.ProducerStage$DefaultProducerStage.createLogic(ProducerStage.scala:41)
    at akka.kafka.internal.ProducerStage$DefaultProducerStage.createLogic(ProducerStage.scala:33)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No serviceName defined in either JAAS or Kafka config
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.kerberos.KerberosLogin.getServiceName(KerberosLogin.java:297)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.kerberos.KerberosLogin.configure(KerberosLogin.java:87)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.LoginManager.<init>(LoginManager.java:52)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.LoginManager.acquireLoginManager(LoginManager.java:89)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.SaslChannelBuilder.configure(SaslChannelBuilder.java:114)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:140)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.clientChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:65)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:88)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:413)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.<init>(KafkaProducer.java:318)
```

Comment: You could either set producer config `sasl.jaas.config` or provide a static config file. See https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_jaas_client for further details.

Comment: have you managed to solve it?